# How is SSE implemented in SignalR?

Tags: signalr, server-sent-events

I'm curious to find out how Server Sent Events, SSE, is implemented in SignalR - **on the server side**. I've looked at the code but can't find the implementation. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see *implementation* of server sent events in SignalR. Do you mean *usage*?

Comment: As far as I know there is no standard way of _using_ SSE in the Asp.NET stack, so I believe there must be an implementation in SignalR.

Comment: [`ServerSentEventsTransport`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Transports/ServerSentEventsTransport.cs)?